# Why is my ffmpeg stream subprocess freezing at 6 minutes?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg pipeline in a shell script that is launched as a subprocess in Python. For some reason, when Python launches the script, my video streams perfectly and then freezes at about six minutes every time. After it freezes, if I tried to run the script manually, it gives me this error:

> Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxcb_connection_has_error() returned true
>   Failed to symlink
>   /root/.pulse/65f3ded611649c6dcf9ebae20000046d-runtime to
>   /tmp/pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n: Input/output error [alsa @ 0x4b2f0] cannot
>   open audio device hw:0,0 (Device or resource busy) hw:0,0:
>   Input/output error

However, if I restart and run the script manually, the audio & video will play fine indefinitely.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks.

Here is my pipline.sh file:

```
sudo ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video7 -f alsa  -i hw:0,0 -map 0:0 -map 1:0  -b:v 120k -bufsize 120k -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -acodec aac -strict -2  -f flv -metadata streamName= StreamName tcp://71.192.1.22
```

And this is the subprocess I'm using in Python:

```
subprocess.Popen("sudo ./ffmpeg_script.sh", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My *guess*: the script isn't draining the stdout pipe quickly enough, and it's filling up with debugging output to the point that ffmpeg's stdout runs out of buffer space and it freezes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm searching through the python docs for a way to drain it as it fills up.  Any idea how I'd go about it?

Comment: Do you actually care about that data? If so, process it as it comes in or set stdout to a tempfile that you can parse later at your leisure. If not, don't capture it at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I don't need the data.  Got it working using stdout=None, stderr=None.  Wasn't working at first cuz I didn't cap 'None'.

Comment: Well, I thought I had it. It works from the terminal, but when my python script is launched with upstart, the ffmpeg subprocess doesn't start.

Comment: *That* part is probably due to $PATH having a different value in your terminal and in upstart. Make sure you have ffmpeg in upstart's $PATH, or add the full path to ffmpeg in your script.